# Histogram - Going down a line when having 2+ letters of same word

Tags: python

I have a question saying this:

---

Write a function which receives a string ( containing only small letters and whitespaces ).

This function will print histogram for all letters with *, for example:

string - "aba ima", this will be printed:

---

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

**      *   *

*

*
```

---

Now, I tried this code, although it is 80% done, the remaining 20% of the work I cant seem to get it...

My problem is how to print the other letters in the string.

For example, aba ima, it has three "a", I cant seem to get it to print 3 lines for it.

My code:

```
def histogram(string):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    for letter in abc:
        if letter in string:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "_")
    return abc


print(histogram("aba ima"))
```

my output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**______*___*_____________
```

can anyone help me? so I can do if it says: aba ima, so Ill have 3 lines of *?

I asked the same question in a forum in my country, no one could help me.
Asked the same at reddit, same thing.
I gave up on it almsot, then decided to ask here to see if any different...
I was told in all scenarios that I have to use index and find, but I cant seem to understand how I need to use it with this function.. its really annoying, I am stuck on it for a week + and because of it I cant continue on to my next homework ( sorting and then recursions ).
Please help on this if anyone can, thanks...

EDIT:

another try of my code, didnt upload but now I will:

```
def make_counters(alphabet):
    counters = []
    for i in range(0, len(alphabet)):
        counters.append(0)  # must be a counter, so integer
    return counters

abc = make_counters("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

def histogram(string, alphabet):
    print(alphabet)
    counters = make_counters(alphabet)
    for letter in alphabet:
        if letter in alphabet:
            alphabet.find(letter)
        else:
            pass



print(histogram("aba ima", abc))
```

SECOND EDIT:
like that?

def histogram(string):

```
  abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    for letter in abc:
        if letter in string:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
            string = string.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            print(abc)
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "_")
    return abc
```

the output is:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
*bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**______*jklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**______*___*nopqrstuvwxyz
**______*___*_____________
```

Process finished with exit code 0

THIRD EDIT:

```
def histogram(string):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    for letter in abc:
        if letter in string:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
            string = string.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            if letter in string:
                abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
                string = string.replace(letter, "*", 1)
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "_")
    print(abc)
    return abc
```

output:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**______*___*_____________
**______*___*_____________
```

tried this also in the third edit ( among some other stuff, this seems like the closest:

```
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    for letter in abc:
        if letter in string:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
            string = string.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            if letter in string:
                    print(abc)
                    abc = abc.replace(letter, "*")
                    string = string.replace(letter, "*", 1)
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(letter, "_")
    print(abc)
    return abc

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
*bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**______*___*_____________
**______*___*_____________
```

but still not good

Comment: I know it wouldnt work, thats the maximum I reached...

Comment: I tried alot of stuff, but nothing works to me... Ill edit the post and you will see how much tries I had...
I tried using count, index, find, nothing....

Comment: And how do you want me to loop multiple times? if I multiple loop, Ill have the same thing over and over again.. same output

Comment: I'm not sure what your latest version is supposed to do. You don't use counters after you create it (and you can do that with `counters = [0] * len(alphabet)` by the way. and you don't print anything at all inside the loop.

Comment: You won't have the same thing again and again if you do what I said, for example, if you start with `"aba ima"` as your string and parse it, but do `string.replace(letter, '', 1) each time you find a letter, you will have `"a a"` left in the string after the first loop. If you then loop across it again, you would have `" a"`. You could then stop looping over it as there are no letters left.

Comment: I am not sure myself, sadly...
about how i can do, it doesnt  really matter...
the print is important, cus look at the output - I need to print the alphabet to see exactly where the * should be, thats why I printed it ( basically it also says to do it, the question ).

Comment: @DavidBuck sadly I dont know how to Parse.
I didnt learn such things, the course teacher told us to use only stuff we learned, which is:
functions, lists - thats it. no counter, no dict, no collections, only functions and lists ( the basic stuff )

Comment: Have you read my last comment? If you add `string = string.replace(letter, '', 1)` into your loop (the original example), it will remove one of each letter you find from `string` as you parse it. You can then loop over it again (you'll need to copy the alphabet back into `abc` before you start. If you print `abc` at the end of each loop across it, you will basically get what you want.

Comment: @DavidBuck can you look at the edit of my post? about the string = string.replace, add it there? ( look at my placement ), cus I really didnt understand where I should add it, and what is the point of that... aww, its really annoying I cant understand what people say about it...

Comment: Getting there. You should move the print to after the loop so that it only prints after you have parsed all of the characters in `abc`, and then wrap the existing loop and print inside another loop (remembering to reset `abc` back to the alphabet at the start of each loop).

Comment: @DavidBuck Hi, Thanks.
Hi, Thanks again for answering me so many times, really appreciate!!,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,currently I did the print(abc) to after the for loop ended...............................
Now, according to you , i need to build inside my for loop another loop....................................
The problem is, it just prints the same thing all over, the new loop should have the same strats as as the first loop no? but its not working: ( THIRD EDIT at POST )

Comment: Recursion could be your friend

Comment: ahh we actually just learnt it, but the histogram was before we learnt it, so we cant use it.........................
But it doesnt matter anymore, I managed to get my course teacher to help me with it, so friday ill be able to get answer to it....................
Sorry for all the mess here and my un-understandness of the material here.
Thanks all! ( no need to comment as im kind of found a solution, hopefully friday ).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this:

- Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to count all letters of the text
- Add an asterisk if the row number is *lower* than the letter count, otherwise add a space

Here's my code:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

def histogram(text):
    letters = Counter(text.casefold())
    hist = ""
    for row in range(max(letters.values())):
        hist += "\n\n"
        for ltr in ascii_lowercase:
            hist += "*" if letters[ltr] > row else " "
    # Add the histogram headers [a-z] before the histogram:
    return ascii_lowercase + hist
```

```
>>> print(histogram("foo bar baz"))
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

**   *        *  *       *

**            *
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Sadly we haven't learned counter and collections ( only def and list till that point ). But its a good solution so when I will learn it, I will take a look as it will help me understand more the material, thanks!

Comment: No problem @BenShaines! A `collections.Counter` object behaves almost exactly as a `dict` object. Once you learn python dictionaries, counters should be super easy to understand, and they are very useful from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

Well a very simple recursion example could be:

```
def histogram(str):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    r = str
    for i in abc:
        if i in r:
            abc = abc.replace(i,"*")
            if r.count(i)  == 1:
                r = r.replace(i,"")
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(i," ")
    print(abc)
    if len(r):
        histogram(r[1:].replace(" ",""))
```

then

```
print("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
histogram("aba ima")
```

would give this outcome

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
**      *   *
*
*
```

Hope it gets you closer to your goal, note that this is not really a general solution since it just works well enouch for your example! this means it works for a char that occures multiple times, if you have more chars occuring more then once you need to work out what you pass into the recursive call of histogramm.

for example if you have more then one b too you end up with a screwed histogram since the call in the function simply omits the first char in the rest string and this would cause more iterations!

**Update**

for a more generic use of this, still not very efficant but for the sake of figuring it out i keep it this way.

```
def histogram(str):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    d = {}
    r = ""
    for i in abc:
        if i in str:
            abc = abc.replace(i,"*")
            if str.count(i)  > 1:
                d.update({i: str.count(i)})
        else:
            abc = abc.replace(i," ")
    print(abc)
    r = "".join([ k for k in d.keys() for x in range(d[k] - 1)])
    if len(r):
        histogram(r)
```

here i use a dict to count the apperance of chars that are in your string more then once. then i make a new string out of the dict but decrease the count of the chars by one.

cheers

Markus

Comment: Thanks, it is pretty hard for me to understand, as I recently learnt recursions ( didnt get the chance to practice cus I was stuck on the histogram ).
But if ill get the chance to practice recursions, ill look at the solution you gave me and try to understand it later, cus now I really dont see me understanding it ( recursions ).
Also, it was preferred to use lists only because till the histogram we haven't learned recursion yet. ( but its good also because its a good practice for me later on ).
Also, cant understand  how it is simple lol, its pretty hard one.
Thanks!

Comment: `str` is Python class. Try to avoid using it as variable name.

Comment: So? I stated that in my Post and Pointed out it only works for the specific Problem. The 2nd Version is Times to be more General

Comment: Wow, huge thanks. I see lots of answers here, really thanks to you all!!! but its really all good :)

Comment: dont worry most people tent to be very clever and smart about things and forget that other who start the journey of learning a language or some paradigm of computer science might have a hard time getting it. So we have to tell ourselfs "slow down, take a step back and explain it in a way a beginner can grasp it". So sorry for some confusion on the way but as you notice most of the asnwers  here (not mine) are very nice indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I was resisting posting a solution as I thought it would be beneficial for you to work it out, but you have a couple of posted solutions now so I'll complete what I was suggesting. Using your latest iteration as a starting point, it doesn't need much modification to do what you want:

```
def histogram(text):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    row = '*'
    while '*' in row:
        row = abc  # You'd need to copy abc fresh every loop, so you do the replace()
        for letter in abc:
            if letter in text:
                row = row.replace(letter, "*")
                text = text.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            else:
                row = row.replace(letter, " ")
        print(row)
```

This basically a) wraps it in a simple `while` loop (you need to set `row = '*'` the first time to make sure the loop runs) b) makes a copy of `abc` each time as `row` c) prints `row` each time it's complete.

You don't actually need to do the replace of the letters in `row` - an alternative could be just to build up the string that you want to print.

```
def histogram(text):
    abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    print(abc)
    row = '*'
    while '*' in row:
        row = ""
        for letter in abc:
            if letter in text:
                row += "*"
                text = text.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            else:
                row += " "
        print(row)
```

As all you want to do is print, some of this is actually unnecessary - you can print directly without needing a string like `row`. The key is to know that if you add `end = ''` to a print statement, it will stop it from adding a line feed after each print. As you don't have `row` you need another means of tracking if you have finished. You can do this by using a boolean like `done`. Again, it needs to be set before you enter the loop.

```
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print(abc)
done = False
while not done:
    done = True
    for letter in abc:
        if letter in text:
            print("*", end='')
            text = text.replace(letter, "*", 1)
            done = False
        else:
            print(" ", end='')
    print()
```

I'm sure there are lots of other ways of attacking this problem, each with their different merits and complexities, which will become more obvious with experience. Personally I'd be tempted to write it like this (which is functionally very similar to @janq0's answer (which I borrowed...) but uses a comprehension rather than a loop), but @janq0's version is easier to read (`ascii_lowercase` is only used to save you typing out all the letters):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

def histogram(text):
    print(ascii_lowercase)
    letters = Counter(text.lower())
    for row in range(max(letters.values())):
        print(f"{''.join('*'  if letters[ltr] > row else ' ' for ltr in ascii_lowercase)}")
```

A final note - in your question you have mixed printing inside the function and outside, which is probably not ideal. With the above, I've printed inside the function, so you'd call as `histogram(text)`, but the alternative is just to add everything to a string and call with `print(histogram(text))`, but then you'll need to add a linefeed `\n` for every line break. You could do that by, e.g.:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import Counter

def histogram(text):
    output = ascii_lowercase
    letters = Counter(text.lower())
    for row in range(max(letters.values())):
        output += f"\n{''.join('*'  if letters[ltr] > row else ' ' for ltr in ascii_lowercase)}"
    return output
```

Comment: Wow, really thanks dude for the detailed answer..........the first answer I actually understood, finally one answer I actually understood at my level hehe, ill try to undrestand the others once I get better at some stuff which are needed............ the last and before, didnt really understand as I dont know counter yet, but when ill do know, I will take a look as it might also help me.... to summarize, thank you, alot!!